# kerberos config single kdc with multiple domains

Tags: realm, kerberos, kdc

we are trying to config a single kerberos server with multiple domains (its a requisite) , so I ended up creating 2 databases like that and some principals in each database (verything is fine, I can log into both database and see the diferent principals ) :

kdc.conf

```
[realms]
EXAMPLE1.COM =
{database_module=EXAMPLE1.COM
...}
EXAMPLE2.COM =
{database_module=EXAMPLE2.COM
...}

[dbmodules]
EXAMPLE1.COM=
{database_name=/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/principal
...}
EXAMPLE2.COM =
{database_name=/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/principal2
...}
```

The krb5.conf looks like that :

```
[realms]
EXAMPLE1.COM=
{ kdc= server.example1.com
admin_server = server.example1.com
default_domain = example1.com
...}
EXAMPLE2.COM =
{kdc= server.example2.com:61321
admin_server = server.example2.com:61321
default_domain = example2.com
...}

[domain_realm]
.example1.com = EXAMPLE1.COM
example1.com = EXAMPLE1.COM
.example2.com = EXAMPLE2.COM
example2.com = EXAMPLE2.COM
```

Now the problem is that kerberos seems to not accept the kdc with different realms for example2 (but it works for example1) :

```
kinit -V -t /tmp/krb5.example2.keytab user/example2@EXAMPLE2.com
keytab specified, forcing -k
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: user/example2@EXAMPLE2.com
Using keytab: /tmp/krb5.example2.keytab
kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'EXAMPLE2.com' while getting initial credentials
```

After the modifications suggested grawity by I edited the service file with systemctl edit --full krb5kdc.service and placed at the end -r EXAMPLE1 -r EXAMPLE2 and now it seems to work better but Im still getting an error I cannot understand (not sure if I should add diferent ports or what is happening) :

```
kinit -V -t /tmp/krb5.example2.keytab user/example2@EXAMPLE2.COM
keytab specified, forcing -k
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_0
Using principal: user/example2@EXAMPLE2.COM
Using keytab: /tmp/krb5.example2.keytab
[355090] 1573732431.376189: Getting initial credentials for user/example2@EXAMPLE2.COM
[355090] 1573732431.376190: Looked up etypes in keytab: aes256-cts, aes128-cts, des3-cbc-sha1, rc4-hmac, des-hmac-sha1, des, des-cbc-crc
[355090] 1573732431.376192: Sending unauthenticated request
[355090] 1573732431.376193: Sending request (201 bytes) to CPD4PRE.NEO4J.GENCAT.CAT
[355090] 1573732431.376194: Resolving hostname host.example2.com
[355090] 1573732431.376195: Initiating TCP connection to stream 10.53.48.79:88
[355090] 1573732431.376196: Sending TCP request to stream 10.53.48.79:88
[355090] 1573732431.376197: Received answer (218 bytes) from stream 10.53.48.79:88
[355090] 1573732431.376198: Terminating TCP connection to stream 10.53.48.79:88
[355090] 1573732431.376199: Response was not from master KDC
[355090] 1573732431.376200: Received error from KDC: -1765328370/KDC has no support for encryption type
[355090] 1573732431.376201: Getting initial credentials for user/example2@EXAMPLE2.COM
[355090] 1573732431.376202: Looked up etypes in keytab: aes256-cts, aes128-cts, des3-cbc-sha1, rc4-hmac, des-hmac-sha1, des, des-cbc-crc
[355090] 1573732431.376204: Sending unauthenticated request
[355090] 1573732431.376205: Sending request (201 bytes) to EXAMPLE2.COM (master)
kinit: KDC has no support for encryption type while getting initial credentials
```

Actually I didnt read the thing about it was needed diferent ports, so I have modified it in order to use 61321 but its not pushing up any socket on that port, its just pushing the default port 88 which Im asuming is for the first (and default) realm :
   {kdc= server.example2.com:61321
   admin_server = server.example2.com:61321

root@example1.com:/root# netstat -netapl | grep LISTEN | grep krb
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:88              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9326395    362136/krb5kdc
tcp6       0      0 :::88                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          9326396    362136/krb5kdc
root@example1.com:/root# ps -ef | grep -i krb
root     362136      1  0 13:04 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/krb5kdc -P /var/run/krb5kdc.pid -r EXAMPLE1.COM -r EXAMPLE2.COM
root     363981 331025  0 13:08 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i krb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your [realms] database_module configuration does not match the [dbmodules] configuration. You have `database_module=EXAMPLE1` but the actual module section is called `EXAMPLE1.com`.

(The configuration layout/syntax also seems really wonky. I hope that's just an artifact of copy&pasting it, and not the actual way it looks?)

---

Second, in MIT Kerberos, the KDC process (krb5-kdc) must be started with a `-r` parameter for each realm. If not specified, it will simply use the system-wide `default_realm` – it will not enumerate all configured databases.

Edit the systemd krb5-kdc.service, or the init.d script, to run:

```
krb5kdc -r EXAMPLE1.COM -r EXAMPLE2.COM
```

Unfortunately, the same *cannot* be achieved with MIT Kerberos' `kadmind` in the current versions – it only supports one database per instance. You can run multiple kadmind instances (on different TCP ports), or use `kadmin.local` for management.

---

Finally, your `kinit` doesn't actually show whether it's contacting the correct KDC in the first place. (And you didn't include any KDC logs indicating that, either.)

You can make the Kerberos clients more verbose by exporting `KRB5_TRACE=/dev/stderr`.

---

Also note that traditionally realm names are *fully* uppercase, the TLD included. So although `EXAMPLE1.com` is perfectly valid, it's not quite what the software expects by default. For example, if you didn't have a [domain_realm] section, clients would try to automatically map the domain to a fully-uppercase realm, not to the mixed version you currently have.

Comment: Im sorry , everything about the typos was because I didnt want to paste the full 
 original config file . You are right are just mistakes when typing, in the original server everything is rightly written and match .

Comment: [343203] 1573731393.691005: Received error from KDC: -1765328370/KDC has no support for encryption type
[343203] 1573731393.691006: Getting initial credentials for user/example2@EXAMPLE2.com
[343203] 1573731393.691007: Looked up etypes in keytab: aes256-cts, aes128-cts, des3-cbc-sha1, rc4-hmac, des-hmac-sha1, des, des-cbc-crc
[343203] 1573731393.691009: Sending unauthenticated request
[343203] 1573731393.691010: Sending request (201 bytes) to EXAMPLE2.COM (master)
kinit: KDC has no support for encryption type while getting initial credentials

Comment: I think the error is related to not placing correctly the ports at /etc/krb.conf, but Ive configured different ports for the second realm with no luck since there is no  socket for the listening port from the second realm, just the default :88

Comment: One kdc process _can_ serve multiple realms on the same port, only kadmind cannot.

Comment: Hi there, finally I solved this by recreating the EXAMPLE2.COM database (deleting and creating again) , thanks a lot